# how _w64 works differently for 32 bit and 64 bit platform

Tags: c

i have some variables defined as

```
typedef _W64 long LONG_PTR, *PLONG_PTR;
```

and then i have  a define for

```
typedef LONG_PTR            LPARAM;
#define _W64 __w64
```

now i have to build it for both 32 and 64 bit. at certain point i have a LPARAM variable and i just typecast another variable as long and passed and it crashed but if typecast as LPARAM it work.
  So my question is isn't the both ways are same to typecast to long. and if not then how _w64 works and make sure that it use long appropriately for 32 and 64 bit?

Or in short what exactly _w64 do?

Regards,
Vivek

Comment: Please format your post correctly. There is the `{}` button to mark programming text.

Comment: @jens Actually the programming text was just for example.i am more knee in working of _w64 and how it handle variables according to platform

Comment: vivek @JensGustedt's comment was not about the actual material of the question, it's about its formatting, which you didn't do and thus he ended up doing it for you.

Comment: Just put more care into posting something here, mark code as code, use proper English and give us enough information such that we can help you. I for example have no idea what `_w64` could be, because you don't even tell us on what type of platform you are.

Comment: There's no `_w64` in your question - there's a `_W64` (one leading underscore, uppercase W) and a `__w64` (two leading underscores). Either way, identifiers with leading underscores and/or double-underscores are reserved for the implementation. What they do is specific to a particular compiler and its library. In this case, because `LPARAM` is a well-known type from the WIN32 API, it's probably something to do with either Visual C++ or perhaps the WIN32 (or MFC) library from MinGW or similar.

Comment: It turns out that these are from Visual C++, and have been considered deprecated since at least 2009 - see [this StackOverflow link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686332/how-do-i-use-w64-and-w64-in-vc).